# Microblog table relationship with foreign key, trouble with followers?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm having a small problem thinking a small microblog system i'm doing for exercise. I have three tables:

```
users
  id
  username

tweets
  id
  tweet

followers
  id_user
  id_following
```

How do i make the relationship for followers? id_user and id_following are both PKs that relate to the same table?

Here's my query:

```
CREATE TABLE tweets (
  tweet_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  tweet VARCHAR(140) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (tweet_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;


CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE user_tweets (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  id_user INT NOT NULL,
  id_tweet INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_tweet)
    REFERENCES tweets(tweeth_id)
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  FOREIGN KEY (id_user)
    REFERENCES users(user_id)) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE followers (
  id_user INT NOT NULL REFERENCES users (user_id),
  id_following INT NOT NULL REFERENCES users (user_id),
  PRIMARY KEY (id_user, id_following)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: surely the PK is (id_user,id_following) and they are individually FKs to the same table? Whats your question?

Comment: It is perfectly fine to have 2 FKs in the same table that are PK in one other table.<br>

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines?

```
create table followers (
  id_user integer not null references users (id),
  id_following integer not null references users (id),
  primary key (id_user, id_following)
);
```

If MySQL supported CHECK constraints, you'd also `CHECK (id_user <> id_following)`. But it doesn't. You'd have to use a trigger instead, but it's simpler (and probably not a problem for a Twitter clone) to just let people follow themselves if they want to. I think most of them will quickly tire of following themselves.

> [The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html)